# Log in using a 4-digit PIN, with a password fallback

Tags: login, authentication

Windows 8 has this feature where you can log in with a 4-digit PIN which is really convenient. Is there such a thing in Linux?

In Windows 8, you get five attempts to log in using the PIN, then it reverts to only allowing you to log in with your regular password.

This isn't the same as a password that consists of 4 digits, because there's a fallback to a longer password, and there's a hard limit on the number of PIN attempts.

Comment: Just a four digit pin, nothing else (Smartcard or other token)? Then just set a 4-digit password? I'm not really sure what you're asking here if it's just that.

Comment: @mat I found this info on how it's "different" than a 4 digit password: http://superuser.com/a/495398/190213. Seems to only apply to a tablet interface.

Comment: I don't see any difference except the UI. Is that what you're asking, i.e. if something will present you a numeric keypad for password entry?

Comment: @Mat I guess I want both convenience and security...

Comment: @Mat It looks like in Windows 8, you get five tries to log in using the PIN, then it reverts to the regular password authentication only. So it's a kind of "second, quick password" scheme which helps speed up the login if you know the PIN but doesn't drastically increase the attack surface for those who don't know the PIN. I edited the question to describe briefly how it works, for the benefit of those who aren't familiar with the intricacies of Windows 8.

Comment: This should be doable with [gdm-pin](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeOS/Design/Whiteboards/ScreenLock/PinAuthentication), if it ever sees the light of day.